# Rolling sum with inequality conditionals

Tags: r, sum

I'm working with some historical financial data from multiple companies.

My data.frames/tables have the following form:

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(company = rep(1:2, each = 9),
                 period = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6), # recycled
                 result = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), # recycled
                 filingDate = as.Date(c('2000-01-01', # 1 1
                                        '2000-02-01', # 2 2
                                        '2000-02-02', # 2 3
                                        '2000-03-02', # 2 4
                                        '2000-03-01', # 3 5
                                        '2000-03-02', # 3 6
                                        '2000-04-01', # 4 7
                                        '2000-05-01', # 5 8
                                        '2000-06-01', # 6 9
                                        # company 2
                                        '2000-03-01', # 1 1
                                        '2000-04-01', # 2 2
                                        '2000-04-02', # 2 3
                                        '2000-05-02', # 2 4
                                        '2000-05-01', # 3 5
                                        '2000-06-02', # 3 6
                                        '2000-06-01', # 4 7
                                        '2000-07-01', # 5 8
                                        '2000-08-01'))) # 6 9
dt
#>     company period result filingDate
#>  1:       1      1      1 2000-01-01
#>  2:       1      2      2 2000-02-01
#>  3:       1      2      3 2000-02-02
#>  4:       1      2      4 2000-03-02
#>  5:       1      3      5 2000-03-01
#>  6:       1      3      6 2000-03-02
#>  7:       1      4      7 2000-04-01
#>  8:       1      5      8 2000-05-01
#>  9:       1      6      9 2000-06-01
#> 10:       2      1      1 2000-03-01
#> 11:       2      2      2 2000-04-01
#> 12:       2      2      3 2000-04-02
#> 13:       2      2      4 2000-05-02
#> 14:       2      3      5 2000-05-01
#> 15:       2      3      6 2000-06-02
#> 16:       2      4      7 2000-06-01
#> 17:       2      5      8 2000-07-01
#> 18:       2      6      9 2000-08-01
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

So I here have results reported by two different companies over 6 periods (i.e. quarters). However, companies sometimes notice they reported something wrong, in which case they make restatements. In this example, the companies had to make two restatements (for a total of three reports) for Period 2, and a restatement for Period 3.

The date at which each of these reports/restatements was handed in is shown in `filingDate`.

Now, I want to calculate the known rolling sum of two (or more) periods for each company over time.

If we only had one filing per period, that could be trivially achieved with `dt[, rSum = frollsum(result, 2), by = company]`.

However, since we can have multiple filings per period, we need to filter these down to the most recent filing known at the "current date", since we can have periods restated after following periods have already been filed. An example is company 1's Period 2 restatement on 2000-03-02, after Period 3's filing on 2000-03-01.

So, the expected output would be:

```
#>     company period rSum filingDate
#>  1:       1      1    1 2000-01-01
#>  2:       1      2    3 2000-02-01  # 2 + 1
#>  3:       1      2    4 2000-02-02  # 3 + 1
#>  4:       1      2    5 2000-03-02  # 4 + 1 (optional row, see below)
#>  5:       1      3    8 2000-03-01  # 5 + 3
#>  6:       1      3   10 2000-03-02  # 6 + 4
#>  7:       1      4   13 2000-04-01  # 7 + 6
#>  8:       1      5   15 2000-05-01  # 8 + 7
#>  9:       1      6   17 2000-06-01  # 9 + 8
#> 10:       2      1    1 2000-03-01 
#> 11:       2      2    3 2000-04-01  # 2 + 1
#> 12:       2      2    4 2000-04-02  # 3 + 1
#> 13:       2      3    8 2000-05-01  # 5 + 3
#> 14:       2      3    9 2000-05-02  # 5 + 4
#> 15:       2      4   12 2000-06-01  # 7 + 5
#> 16:       2      4   13 2000-06-02  # 7 + 6
#> 17:       2      5   15 2000-07-01  # 8 + 7
#> 18:       2      6   17 2000-08-01  # 9 + 8
```

There are a few nuances here which should be made explicit.

Looking at rows 4 and 6 of the input table `dt`, we see that Company 1 made two restatements on 2000-03-02, for Periods 2 and 3. Since we have results for Period 3, we are no longer in Period 2, so the relevant "most recent" `rSum` is Period 3's. That is why the expected output above indicates row 4 as optional: I really only care about the `rSum` on row 6, but any solution which includes that dummy result on row 4 is perfectly fine as well.

What's more complicated is what happens in row 15 of the input and 16 of the expected output: Company 2 makes a restatement of its Period 3 results on 2000-06-02. However, by that time we already have results for Period 4 (given on 2000-06-01). So, once again, the "most recent" `rSum` on that date is actually between Periods 3 and 4 (`6 + 7 = 13`), and should be associated with the more recent Period 4, not 3.

I can't see how to do this elegantly. All I can think of is getting all the unique filing dates and doing a for-loop through them, so as to get the most-recent results from previous periods. And note this doesn't even satisfy the second nuance above, since the result on 2000-06-02 is associated with Period 3.

```r
r <- c()
for(comp in unique(dt$company)) {
  x <- dt[company == comp]
  for(d in x[, sort(unique(filingDate))]) {
    y <- tail(x[filingDate <= d,
                .SD[filingDate == max(filingDate)],
                by = .(company, period)], 2)
    r <- c(r, sum(y$result))
  }
}

x <- dt[, .SD[period == max(period)],
        by = .(company, filingDate)]
setorder(x, company, filingDate, period)
x[, rSum := r]
setorder(x, company, period, filingDate)
x
#>     company filingDate period result rSum
#>  1:       1 2000-01-01      1      1    1
#>  2:       1 2000-02-01      2      2    3
#>  3:       1 2000-02-02      2      3    4
#>  4:       1 2000-03-01      3      5    8
#>  5:       1 2000-03-02      3      6   10
#>  6:       1 2000-04-01      4      7   13
#>  7:       1 2000-05-01      5      8   15
#>  8:       1 2000-06-01      6      9   17
#>  9:       2 2000-03-01      1      1    1
#> 10:       2 2000-04-01      2      2    3
#> 11:       2 2000-04-02      2      3    4
#> 12:       2 2000-05-02      2      4    9
#> 13:       2 2000-05-01      3      5    8
#> 14:       2 2000-06-02      3      6   13  # should be Period 4
#> 15:       2 2000-06-01      4      7   12
#> 16:       2 2000-07-01      5      8   15
#> 17:       2 2000-08-01      6      9   17
```

This feels very un-R, though, so is there a more idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: I can't understand the problem, is it that you have multiple results per period per company?

Comment: @Bruno No, each company only has one result. However, they might say "our Period 2 results were 2", but then go "oh, wait, our mistake! The Period 2 results were actually 3". So I initially need to calculate the rolling sum with 2, but then with 3 when I get the corrected results. This is trying to simulate the knowledge I'd have on any given day.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan a problem is that my real case will require doing rolling sums over N periods, just used 2 as an example. I've edited the question to make that clearer.

Comment: i think you might want to check your expected output against sample data set as some rows are missing and some rows are not the same

Comment: I just dont get why you need to keep data that was actually wrong, just keep the oldest instances per company period

Comment: @Bruno this is for a backtest, trying to model how an algorithm (here represented by the rolling sum) would have behaved in the past. If it were 2000-02-01 and company 1 said its Period 2 results were 2, what would the algorithm say? And then what would it say on 2000-02-02, when the corrected figures came in?

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use a non-equi join:

```
winsz <- 2L
dt[, c("start", "end") := .(period - winsz + 1L, period)] 

dt[, rSum :=
    dt[dt, on=.(company, end>=start, end<=end),
        by=.EACHI, i.result +
            #filter right table for rows with periods before current period and filingDate before current filingDate 
            #and select the latest result for each period and then sum those result
            sum(.SD[period<i.period & filingDate<=i.filingDate, result[.N], period]$V1)
    ]$V1
]
```

output:

```
    company period result filingDate start end rSum
 1:       1      1      1 2000-01-01     0   1    1
 2:       1      2      2 2000-02-01     1   2    3
 3:       1      2      3 2000-02-02     1   2    4
 4:       1      2      4 2000-03-02     1   2    5
 5:       1      3      5 2000-03-01     2   3    8
 6:       1      3      6 2000-03-02     2   3   10
 7:       1      4      7 2000-04-01     3   4   13
 8:       1      5      8 2000-05-01     4   5   15
 9:       1      6      9 2000-06-01     5   6   17
10:       2      1      1 2000-03-01     0   1    1
11:       2      2      2 2000-04-01     1   2    3
12:       2      2      3 2000-04-02     1   2    4
13:       2      2      4 2000-05-02     1   2    5
14:       2      3      5 2000-05-01     2   3    8
15:       2      3      6 2000-06-02     2   3   10
16:       2      4      7 2000-06-01     3   4   12
17:       2      5      8 2000-07-01     4   5   15
18:       2      6      9 2000-08-01     5   6   17
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(company = rep(1:2, each = 9),
    period = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    result = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
    filingDate = as.Date(c('2000-01-01','2000-02-01','2000-02-02','2000-03-02','2000-03-01','2000-03-02','2000-04-01','2000-05-01','2000-06-01','2000-03-01','2000-04-01','2000-04-02','2000-05-02','2000-05-01','2000-06-02','2000-06-01','2000-07-01','2000-08-01')))
dt[, filingDate := as.IDate(filingDate, format="%Y-%m-%d")]
```

Comment: I'd managed to get similar results (using a much less efficient `for` loop), but there's a problem which can be seen in row 15 of the result. This is a restatement of Company 2's Period 3 results, given on 2000-06-02. However, by that time we already have results for Period 4, given on 2000-06-01. So the `rSum` after that statement should actually be 13, from the corrected Period 3 results and the known Period 4 result.

Comment: This is related to why my given expected output is lacking a row: your row 4 is a restatement of Company 1's Period 2 results, but it comes on the same day (2000-03-02) as a Period 3 restatement, so the only relevant `rSum` that day is Period 3's. However, this omission is optional, so a solution including the duplicate would also be entirely acceptable.

Comment: If required, we can remove data for older periods which were updated on or after the earliest of the next period